# ValueError: An operation has `None` for gradient

Tags: tensorflow, keras, valueerror

```
inp = keras.layers.Input(shape = (x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2], 1))

conv = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = 8, kernel_size = 3, activation='relu')(inp)
conv = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(conv)
conv = keras.layers.pooling.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = 2)(conv)
conv = keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(conv)

conv = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = 8, kernel_size = 3, activation='relu')(conv)
conv = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(conv)
conv = keras.layers.pooling.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = 2)(conv)
conv = keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(conv)

conv = keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = 16, kernel_size = 3, activation='relu')(conv)
conv = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(conv)
conv = keras.layers.pooling.MaxPooling2D(pool_size = 2)(conv)
conv = keras.layers.Dropout(0.2)(conv)

fc = keras.layers.Flatten()(conv)
fc = keras.layers.Dense(3, kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(fc)

out = keras.layers.Softmax(3)(fc)

cnn = keras.Model(inp, out)
cnn.summary(80)
```

Above is my cnn structure.
I didn't use any customizing layer.

```
#Training
keras.backend.clear_session()
cnn.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
cnn.fit(x = x_train, y = y_train_onehot, validation_data=[x_valid, y_valid_onehot], epochs=20, batch_size=16)
```

Trying this fit code.
Just compile using Adam.

However, an error occur as below.
On fit function, Value Error occurs.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-547159688594> in <module>
      2 keras.backend.clear_session()
      3 cnn.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
----> 4 cnn.fit(x = x_train, y = y_train_onehot, validation_data=[x_valid, y_valid_onehot], epochs=20, batch_size=16)

ValueError: An operation has `None` for gradient. Please make sure that all of your ops have a gradient defined (i.e. are differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, K.round, K.eval.
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: To be clear, are you running this using TensorFlow 2.0 or greater?

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to run `clear_session` _after_ constructing the model...